# ошибка Twig_Error_Runtime Yii

Tags: php, yii, postgresql, twig

Есть сайт на yii1, с шаблонизатором twig, бд - PostgreSQL. Сайт ранее успешно работал на старом сервере. После переноса выдает ошибку:

```
 An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "and"
LINE 3: WHERE customer.visible AND customer.contest_id = and (selec...
^. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT customer.customer_id, count(vote.customer_id) as votes
FROM pr_contest_customer customer LEFT JOIN pr_contest_vote vote ON (vote.customer_id = customer.customer_id)
WHERE customer.visible AND customer.contest_id = and (select id from pr_customer_image image where customer.customer_id = image.customer_id limit 1) is not null
GROUP BY "vote"."customer_id", "customer"."customer_id", "customer"."date_added"
ORDER BY "votes" DESC LIMIT 6") in "/views/site/contest.twig" at line 60.
```

Comment: Там же написано, что ошибка в запросе к бд, он не может его выполнить из за синтаксической ошибки. `Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "and"`

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko , вижу в этом куске  нету значения customer.contest_id = and . Дебагер ругается на 
protected/vendor/Twig/Template.php(148),  т.е виноват шаблонизатор

Comment: было бы хорошо глянуть на код шаблона и контроллера.

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko дело в том что ошибка на всех страницах. вот строка из шаблона где возникает ошибка:
 <ul class="comp-members">
      {% for rating in model('ContestCustomer').rating(contest['id'], 6) %}
 {% include '@widgets/site/contest_customer.twig' %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko  а в экшене просто рендерит представление

Comment: @РоманМальцев шаблонизатор не виноват, виноват функционал, вызываемый шаблонизатором. Судя по SQL, на определенной строчке шаблона вызывается отложенный запрос (lazy load) к модели, который и выкидывает исключение.